# Is it Good to use Active Directory for User and password sync for an Exchange server implementation?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, exchange-server

I was using SMTP to send emails. Now I want to use Exchange server to send/receive emails with individual user mailbox.I have other web application which uses same domain credentials for User authentication which are stored in Database.

```
Now For sync between Exchange server users and users in DB,
```

> Should I go with standalone application which sync credential with
>   exchange server and  credential stored in Database?
>
> or Go with Active directory? Is it easy to manage Active directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install Exchange without Active Directory so there's no way to get around it.  As such, use Active Directory as your master password repository and sync out to alternate applications.

A better solution is to authenticate directly into Active Directory via LDAP, Kerberos, or NTLM.  Using LDAP though also will allow your application to create user hierarchies and security policies based off Active Directory security groups so that gives you an added bonus.

Active Directory is your answer.